# Quiz - removing nodes

Tags: javascript

Why does the current question reappear once it is removed? The aim is to load the next question once the current quesion has been answered. Heres the full [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/vda85aub/107/).

```
function nextquestion(){
   var parentDiv = document.getElementById('myForm');
   var formGroup = document.getElementById('form-group');
   var removedNode = parentDiv.removeChild(formGroup);
   alert(removedNode.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because will reload the page.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="next question"/>
</form>
```

Change to

```
<button onclick=nextQuestion()>next question</button>
```

and hande it without page reloading.

I suggest this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/vda85aub/108/

You delete the old question simplu by calling `question.innerHTML = ''`